# How can I add a link to an image that changes on hover via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image below a nav and the image changes depending on which nav item is hovered over. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav-item').mouseenter(function() {
      var img = $(this).attr('data-headerimg'); 
      $('img#header-img').attr('src', img);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
      var img = $(this).attr('data-headerimg');
      $('img#header-img').attr('src', img);
    });
});
```

I'd like the image to be a link to it's corresponding page, but I'm not sure how to do that via jQuery. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This can most likely be done with CSS !

Comment: any html code for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, enclose the image in an anchor in your HTML: `<a><img ....></a>`. Put the link next to `data-headerimg`, in `data-headerlink` attribute.

Second, update the anchor's `href` to the same value you're setting the image's `src`:

```
var img = $(this).attr('data-headerimg'); 
var href = $(this).attr('data-headerlink'); 
$('img#header-img').attr('src', img).parent().attr('href', href);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorround it with a href tag in html like

```
<a id="headerimglink" href=""><img src="" /></a>
```

set the href attribute along with the src attribute, or you can hardcode it as well if that is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

Why to send an image request and wait a server response with image data? (Some users find it very annoying)
In order to preload your images You can simply create the needed tags and just swap `display` (with fade?) on item hover.

Let's say:

```
<ul id="list">
   <li>Football</li>
   <li>Barbara</li>
</ul>
<div id="images">
   <a href="foo.html"><img src="foo.jpg" alt="Foo"></a>
   <a href="bar.html"><img src="bar.jpg" alt="Bar"></a>
</div>
```

```
#images a {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    /* etc */
}
```

```
var $imgLink = $('#images a');
$('#list li').hover(function( e ) {
  $imgLink.stop().fadeTo(300, 0);
  if(e.type=="mouseenter") {
      $imgLink.eq( $(this).index() ).fadeTo(300, 1);
  }
});
```